# How do I change the path of the ROS folder without affecting its functionality?

Tags: ros

I would like to change the ROS folder location.

The current directory is: root/opt/ros

but if I just move it (cut, paste), ROS doesn't work

How can I move it to my desktop (having ROS still working)?

(I have ROS Diamondback)

Comment: Have you tried to adapt your $ROS_ROOT (and ROS_PACKAGE_PATH) - Environment variables?

Comment: What NikolasE sais should do it. Also you might need to change the absolute path of the ros scripts you source within .bashrc and .bash_profile.

Answer (score 0):

the ros write in the .bashrc where ros is installed to look in this folder when needed. You can change the .bashrc and set the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to the new path where you want to set as the ros folder or change in the ros folder the setup.bash. Maybe, in the .bashrc, this file is called to set the ros variables, you can edit this file and change the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to the path where you will put your ros directory.

Another tip, if you want to add more folders to ros(more folders where it can look for packages) just set ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:new/directories/you/want

I hope it help!